# ASP.NET Core - FormAction never pass in the good method

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, submit

I am beginning to learn ASP.NET Core and I have several submit buttons on my page, but when I submit, the post always goes to the same method. At the beginning, I would like to insert a file upload in my form.

```
<form>
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="annonce_id" />

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="annonce_description" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="annonce_description" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="annonce_description" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Save" formaction="Edition" formmethod="post" class="btn btn-primary" />
        <input type="submit" value="Save2" formaction="Index2" formmethod="post" class="btn btn-primary" />

        <input type="file" name="file" />
        <input type="submit" name="save" value="upload" form="maform1" formaction="UploadFile" formmethod="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" />

    </div>
</form>
```

My controller :

```
public ActionResult Detail(int id)
{
    return View("Detail", Connect_Management.BusinessLayer.AnnonceManager.GetOneById(id));
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edition(Connect_Management.BusinesObject.Annonces annonce)
{
    Connect_Management.BusinessLayer.AnnonceManager.Update(annonce);
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index2(List<IFormFile> files)
{
    //Do something with the files here. 
    return Ok();
}
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFile file)
{
    // full path to file in temp location
    var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();

    return Ok();
}
```

It always uses the following method:

```
public ActionResult Edition(Connect_Management.BusinesObject.Annonces annonce)
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you share more details about your code?I could get into different action by using your code.By the way,you do not have `form="maform1"` in your code,you need to delete this attribute,otherwise,the input would not get into the action.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I can't insert all my code, it's say me that detect to code in my post. form="maform1" was for test. I don't understand why formaction="Index2" or formaction="UploadFile" call public ActionResult Edition(Connect_Management.BusinesObject.Annonces annonce) while public ActionResult Index2(List<IFormFile> files) and public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFile file) methods exists with HttpPost markup.

Comment: Could you share how did you configure route templete in Startup?And did you use route attribute on your controller?

Comment: I suppose you want that in startup.cs ? : public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {  app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
}

Comment: ok i found the solution, i must use asp-action="UploadFile instead of formaction. thanks for your help;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution :

```
use asp-action="UploadFile instead of formaction="UploadFile"
```